# StaticResource not found

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, resources, silverlight-4.0, resourcedictionary

I have the situation where a SolidColorBrush (defined in App.xaml) cannot be resolved during runtime, when i use the Brush in a Style as StaticResource.

During designtime (using Visual Studio 2010) the brush is found, cause when i change the color of the brush the UIElement with the styles are updated with the new color.

During runtime a XAMLParseException is raised, that the resource "color" cannot be found.

Is this a normal behavior? I thought the resolving of StaticResource, starts from the UIElements up to the Application resources and that the Application resources are a good place to define default values (Colors, Fonts, etc.) for the UIElements of the Application.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.App"
         >
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" x:Key="color"/>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Styles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource color}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
</Style>
```

**Main.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Border Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,146,0,0" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the SolidColorBrush into the Styles.XAML?

Comment: @Ardman: This works. But thats not want i want here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored the resource definitions and put the SolidColorBrush "Color" in a ResourceDictionary "General.xaml"

I merged the ResourceDictionary "General.xaml" in the ResourceDictionary "Styles.xaml". Now it works without any problems. I think this is the way to go with resources.

**General.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" x:Key="color"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Styles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="General.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource color}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had some success circumventing issues like these by placing all the styles into XAML resource dictionaries and merging them at runtime.  Merging these same dictionaries in XAML did not solve the issue.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
{
    if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool == false)
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
    }
}

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{           
    System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("/MRW.UI;component/Resources/Library.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    System.Windows.ResourceDictionary dictionary = new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary(); 
dictionary.Source = uri;
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is also the way i choose to add new ResourceDictionaries to the ApplicationResources, for modules that i load during runtime

Comment: took too much time editing the above comment... One other thing that one of my co-workers recently discovered... you can merge the same dictionaries in code and in XAML without error.  This will allow you to work in the Visual Studio or Blend designer and solve the above issue.